# How to route all local windows traffic over a C# TCP Proxy

Tags: c#, windows, networking, tcp, proxy

Basically I want it to act like how PIA (PIA is a VPN service) does, you turn on PIA and all your traffic is routed through the PIA VPN. I want to do the same thing but with my local proxy I built, so it can log all potential data going in and out of my PC.

It works great if I set Firefox or even the windows 10 Proxy setting to use it but I want to be able to run my proxy and have it automatically reroute all traffic through it just like how pia does when you run it.

Do I need a custom networking Adapter like the one PIA installs?

So far I just have running on 127.0.0.1 and port 9806, and then have chrome set to use the proxy and it works great on every site I have tried. Now I just want it work for all traffic on my pc.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: First question: what is PIA?

Comment: I don't think Firefox has settings for TCP Proxy... (Note that in current "explain how TCP interception works, how it is different from HTTP proxy and tell me how to implement both" form the question is *a bit* too broad for SO)

Comment: PIA is Private Internet Access, its a VPN service.

Comment: Look for source code for a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler which is doing a similar functionality.

Comment: Not all traffic is TCP, so you cannot have all traffic through a TCP proxy. VPNs work by routing IP through an interface. Proxies are configured per application.

Comment: Well what If I have a TCP and UDP proxy? A UDP one is not too hard to make as well. I just want all windows traffic to have to go through my proxy application